# Google MapKit in iOS app

Tags: ios, dictionary

For a first time I want  to build a map which shows the current position with the places in it's area and search about them .
I used google maps and I can see my current position on the map but it appears without colours as in the tutorials and the  places from the api does not appear on the map .
I used also the source code of many tutorials and Just I can see the streets .??

Comment: Please refer to the blog : http://www.innofied.com/google-maps-sdk-places-api-integration-ios/ . Hope it helps.

Comment: my last try is this tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/13160/using-the-google-places-api-with-mapkit  . I can see my current location but only the streets appear without places